# Insert multiple rows with VALUES containing IDs inserted in the same query

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert

```
INSERT INTO "public"."Contacts"
  (FirstName, LastName, AddressId)
VALUES
 ('John', 'Doe',
  (INSERT INTO "public"."Addresses" (streetName) VALUES ('1st') RETURNING id)
 ),
  ('Jane', 'Doe',
   (INSERT INTO "public"."Addresses" (streetName) VALUES ('2nd') RETURNING id)
 )
```

I'm looking for a way to insert explicit values using multiple rows in `VALUES` and have the returned ID be a part of those values. Currently as the query stands, it doesn't work, but if it did, it would make a separate `INSERT` for each address.

I know I need to first insert all addresses using multiple `VALUES` again and then somehow use that ID array with the `VALUES` for `Contacts`, but I have no idea how. Anyone can provide any pointers?

Comment: You should **really** avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it.

Comment: i personally would create a stored prcoedure which handles both inserts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the street names that you insert are unique, you could do something like this:

```
with new_data (firstname, lastname, streetname) as (
  values 
    ('John', 'Doe', '1st'),
    ('Jane', 'Doe', '2nd')
)
, new_addresses as (
  insert into addresses (streetname)
  select streetname
  from new_data
  returning id, streetname
)
insert into contacts (firstname, lastname, addressid)
select t.firstname, 
       t.lastname,
       a.id
from new_data t
  join new_addresses a on a.streetname = t.streetname;
```

Again: this **only** works correctly if the streetnames to be inserted are unique (they don't need to be unique in the `addresses` table).

If you can't guarantee that, I don't have an idea how you could do that with a single bulk-insert.

---

<sup>Note that I used different table names than you have in your question - I just loath those quoted identifiers</sup>

Comment: I have no idea what's wrong with quoted identifiers as I am only really just now doing any work with Postres, but your post answered my question, so thanks. :)

Comment: @TomášHübelbauer: there is nothing "wrong" with them, but I find them harder to type and read. But they also introduce problems that you might not have with non-quoted identifiers. e.g. `"Contacts"` is a different name than `Contacts`.  And sometimes tools, frameworks or libraries are just not prepared to deal with them correctly. In the long run they just generate  small and annoying problems that you don't have if you never quote them.

Comment: I see! Thanks for clearing that up, I definitely try to adhere to best practices and it seems reasonable to avoid them given the reasons you laid out.